# AWS ALB gives 504 timeout when vpc cni network policies applied

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-alb, amazon-eks

I've got argocd deployed on EKS, with ingress running on top of AWS Load Balancer Controller.

Alb controller is deployed in `kube-system`. Argo is deployed in `argocd` namespace with internal alb created with ingress annotations. Everything works till I enabled Network Policy via `vpc-cni addon`. Once Network Policy is in place, it also restrict traffic from alb and gives me `504 Gateway Time-out`.

My logic was quite obvious when creating Network Policy. Started with allowing traffic from `kube-system` namespace and `argocd` namespace:

```
  ingress:
    - from:
        - namespaceSelector:
            matchLabels:
              kubernetes.io/metadata.name: argocd
    - from:
        - namespaceSelector:
            matchLabels:
              kubernetes.io/metadata.name: kube-system
```

Tried different combinations of above, even added multiple `from` blocks to cover all namespaces that exists in the cluster. Tried whitelisting by IPs, both eks subnets and even whole vpc cidr.

```
    - from:
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: x.x.x.x/x #ip block used by vpc
```

I looked up other similar issues, extended alb idle time from 60 to 300s didn't change a thing. I'm running out of ideas. Anyone made it work? What am I missing?